# How to schedule a script to run daily on jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, cron, cloud, jupyter, scheduler

I am using Jupyter notebook on internal cloud. And there is a script which needs to be run daily. Is there a way to automate it so that it runs itself on a daily basis?

I read somewhere that this can be done using Cron, so I tried installing the following and every time it gives the following error:

```
!pip install jupyterlab-scheduler

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyterlab-scheduler (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jupyterlab-scheduler

!pip install jupyter-cron

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyter-cron (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jupyter-cron
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason you can't convert your Jupyter notebook to a regular Python script that could be launched directly from cron, no special installation required?

Comment: You can try simple_scheduler. Its easy to use - [examples] (https://github.com/Vernal-Inertia/simple_scheduler/tree/main/examples)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to give credit to @Vincent Stevenson

If you are using Windows 10, you can do the following:

Save your jupyter notebook as .py file

Go to `Control Panel --> Administrative Tools --> Task Scheduler--> Create Task`

1. Task Scheduler, Create Task
2. Give the Task a title
3. Go to Actions
4. Go to CMD to find the path,

   Python, import sys, sys.executable

   (this tells you what the **Program/script field** should be populated with: "some path
   with Appdata mostly")

   like:C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
5. **Arguments**: name of the python script (like run.py)
6. **Start in**: dir location of python script (like:C:\Users\admin\Documents\my_python_project)
7. Go to Triggers, schedule for Daily
8. Test the script by running it

Answer (score 0):

There are [several approaches for scheduling Jupyter Notebooks](https://mljar.com/blog/schedule-jupyter-notebook/). To execute the notebook with cron, you need to define a line in the crontab with the:

- crontab string that defines execution frequency,
- a command that will be executed.

For the crontab string, I recommend https://crontab.guru/ - it helps you define schedule expressions.

For command, please check [nbconvert](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert) and [papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill) - they allow you to execute .ipynb file in the command line.

If you would like to schedule notebooks and share them with others, please check [Mercury](https://github.com/mljar/mercury) or [Notebooker](https://github.com/man-group/notebooker) frameworks. They offer a web-based service for scheduling and sharing final notebooks as HTML.